# Getting the 'offerId' on a new Offer and any documentation on 'xdr.ManageOfferOp'?

Tags: javascript-sdk, trade, manageoffer

I'm using the [JS-SDK](https://github.com/stellar/js-stellar-sdk) to make offers.

An issue I am having though is getting the `offerId` from a new offer.  The `offerId` is required to manage a pre-existing offer.  As such, it seems that the `offerId` should be returned with the response object from a submitted transaction.

Once a transaction is submitted to the network an object is returned `xdr.ManageOfferOp`. I feel the `offerId` should be available within that object but I am not finding any straight-forward way of extracting that `offerId`.

Is there something I am missing?  There doesn't seem to be much documentation on the response object `xdr.ManageOfferOp`.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

In the above scenario I was able to fish out the `offerId`:

```
_attributes.result._value[0]._value._value._value._attributes.offersClaimed[0]._attributes.offerId
```

from the response object. The `offerId` is nested in both `result_xdr` and `result_meta_xdr`.

However, this seems very hacky.

Moreover, `offerId` is an object:

```
"offerId": {"low":6703677, "high":0, "unsigned":true}
```

What is `low` and `high`?

In this particular scenario, the offer was consumed the moment it went on the exchange as there was a pre-existing offer that matched to it.  hat pre-existing offer, looking through the data, was assigned the `offerId` of 6703677.  So does `low` indicate the `offerId` of the consuming offer?  Had my offer persisted on the network and been assigned it's own `offerId`, would that then be assigned to `offerId.high`?

Some documentation or insight on this object itself would be useful.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with offer id after the `ManageOffer` operation, and I came to the same solution. If you don't have a lot of orders and don't mind to make an extra request, you can also pull [account offers](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/offers-for-account.html) endpoint after submitting the `ManageOffer` to get all active offers and update you client-side offers state. Since `OfferCreated`/`OfferRemoved` effects are [not implemented](https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/166), it's the only way to get current offer status.

Offer ID is saved in `int64` format. XDR format [supports 64-bit integers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1014#section-3.5), however JavaScript does not support 64-bit integers natively.

That's why bigint numbers are encoded as two 32-bit numbers (`low` and `high`). `unsigned` means that the encoded bigint number is an unsigned integer.

In order to work with bigint numbers in JavaScript (NodeJS or browser), one have to use libraries like [bignumber.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bignumber.js).

Comment: Thank you for the response.

I was thinking about calling the account offers endpoint as a work around.  Glad to know I'm not alone.

Appreciate your explanation on int64 and XDR.  The 'offerId' object makes much more sense knowing that.  

Thank you again.